# How to send data in these <div>s to the server using JSON?

Tags: jquery, html

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add').click(function() {
      alert('added');
      $(this).before('<div class="block" style="color:blue">Name:<select> <option>Mr</option> <option>Mrs</option> <option>Miss</option> </select> <input type="text"/> <input type="text"/> <input type="text"/> <br> <label style="color:red; margin-left:160px">name</label> <label style="color:red; margin-left:80px">Father/Husband Name</label> <label style="color:red; margin-left:50px">Surname</label><br>date of birth: <input type="date"/><br>contact:</select> <input type="text"> <input type="text"/> <input type="text"/> <br><label style="color:red; margin-left:110px">Email</label> <label style="color:red; margin-left:120px">Phone1</label> <label style="color:red; margin-left:100px">Phone2</label><br>Relation with Head:<select><option>Father</option><option>Mother</option><option>Sister</option></select><br><br><center> <span class="remove">Remove Individual</span></center><hr></div>');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
      alert('removed');
      $(this).parent('div').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2> Basic Information </h2>
<!-- Line1-->
Surname:
<input type="text" />Caste:
<select>
  <option>Hindu</option>
  <option>Muslim</option>
</select>
Sub-caste:
<select>
  <option>Hindu</option>
  <option>Muslim</option>
</select>

<!-- Line2-->
<br>Address:
<textarea style="margin-top:20px;"></textarea>
District:
<input type="text" />Pincode:
<input type="text" />

<!-- Line3-->
<br>State:
<select>
  <option>Maharashtra</option>
  <option>Gujarat</option>
</select>
City/village:
<input type="text" />
<br>

<!-- Line2-->
<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Same as above
<br>

<!-- Line1-->
<br>Surname:
<input type="text" />Caste:
<select>
  <option>Hindu</option>
  <option>Muslim</option>
</select>
Sub-caste:
<select>
  <option>Hindu</option>
  <option>Muslim</option>
</select>

<!-- Line2-->
<br>Address:
<textarea style="margin-top:20px;"></textarea>
District:
<input type="text" />Pincode:
<input type="text" />
<br>
<!-- Line3-->
State:
<select>
  <option>State1</option>
  <option>State2</option>
  < /select>
    City/village:
    <input type="text" />
    <br>
    <!-- Line2-->


    <h2> Member 's Information</h2>
    <div class="optionBox">
      <div class="block">
        <hr>Name:
        <select>
          <option>Mr</option>
          <option>Mrs</option>
          <option>Miss</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <br>

        <label style="color:red; margin-left:160px">name</label>
        <label style="color:red; margin-left:80px">Father/Husband Name</label>
        <label style="color:red; margin-left:50px">Surname</label>
        <br>date of birth:
        <input type="date" />
        <br>contact:
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <br>
        <label style="color:red; margin-left:110px">Email</label>
        <label style="color:red; margin-left:120px">Phone1</label>
        <label style="color:red; margin-left:100px">Phone2</label>
        <br>Relation with Head:
        <select>
          <option>Father</option>
          <option>Mother</option>
          <option>Sister</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <br>
        <center><span class="remove">Remove Individual</span>
        </center>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        <span class="add">Add Individual</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When I add more elements in the div. for ex. in case of a large form; the div populates however, the  doesnt get removed. For example I have this jquery snippet. Here, on click of add button the  is added. However, on click of remove button; the div doesnt get removed.

I also want to assign each  elements a separate ID and I want to pack it into JSON. Any suggestions for this one?

Comment: you can `transfer the class add to the button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**:

1- You added click event on `.add` so you have to change your selector to`$('.add input').click(function()`.

2- You have a syntax error in your html

```
<span class="add"><input type=button value="Add Individual"></span>
```

You missed `"`.

```
<span class="add"><input type="button" value="Add Individual"></span>
```

Comment: @Nevermore Can you post your completed code or provide a demo?

Comment: I will provide it in JSFiddle.. just a moment

Comment: I have inserted a JSFiddle for a demo.

Comment: It works perfectly as needed. However, I also need to get the data from these <div>s into a JSON array.

Comment: @Nevermore What do you mean by `get the data from these <div>s` into a JSON array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95768/discussion-between-nevermore-and-alireza-safian).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95776/discussion-between-alireza-safian-and-nevermore).

Answer (score 1):

Try **$('.add input')** instead of **$('.add')** like below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add input').click(function() {
        $(this).before('<div class="block"><input type="text" />\ <span class="remove">Remove Individual</span><br><hr></div>');
    });

});
```

> Use for Remove

```
$(document).on('click','.remove',function() {
    alert('removed');
    $(this).closest("div.block").remove();
});
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and the answer given 3 minutes ago?

Comment: No difference.. @alireza safian Your answer was correct. Why did you delete your answer??

Comment: @Nevermore, just replace this $(this).closest("div.block").remove();

Comment: @KaushikMaheta Yes it works correctly. However, I need to assign separate ids to each of the <div> elements to get distinct info from each <div>.

Answer (score 1):

```
<span class="add"><input type=button value="Add Individual"></span>
```

here **button** are not quoted that's why not work change them to

```
<span class="add"><input type="button" value="Add Individual"></span>
```

**it work's perfect**

**HTML**

```
<form>  
    <div class="optionBox">
        <div class="block">
            <input type="text" /> <span class="remove">Remove Individual</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <input type="text" /> <span class="remove">Remove Individual</span><br>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <span class="add"><input type="button" value="Add Individual"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.add').click(function() {
            $(this).before('<div class="block"><input type="text" />\ <span class="remove">Remove Individual</span><br><hr></div>');
        });
        $(document).on('click','.remove',function() {
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```